# Merging webforms and mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We have 2 teams one working in webforms and another in mvc3. Everything was working finely until client asked us to combine both these sites.

So we are asked to create an app with a dashboard listing features of both apps and navigating to each page on selection. The basic idea is that we should have a feeling of one application

So we are posed with 2 problems.
1. How to perform single sign in and sign out across application
2. Navigation between  apps.

For the second problem we are having 2 plans 
1. Removing the master page of both pages and show inside an iframe 
2. Redirecting to the url of app

Is there any other better options. anyways single sig-nin would be a problem.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of building so many crutches, maybe, you may want to migrate to the single framework? Obviously, to ASP.NET MVC, better 5. Is this WebForms application too large? What is the cost of this migration? Imagine how many problems you may encounter and how many bad things like `iframes` you will have to do.

Comment: Yeah that's the problem.Both are huge applications. we have only 2 month duration.We are looking for some efficient and quick solutions